How to access data in an h5 file?
I downloaded an astronomical data file called sources.h5 from this webpage. I am trying to access it to no avail. What I achieved doing is:
source_cat = h5py.File('sources.h5', 'r')
print(source_cat.keys())
>>> <KeysViewHDF5 ['_types', 'sources']>

print(source_cat['sources']
>>> <HDF5 dataset "sources": shape (), type "|V136">

data = source_cat['sources'][()]
print(data)
>>> (<HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>, 230355498, 51400878)

But if I do
print(source_cat['sources'][:10])

I get the error message ValueError: Illegal slicing argument for scalar dataspace
Do you have any ideas how I can get to the data inside the file? And not only for the sources, but also _types key? Further, if you can share a program/code that would show me the three of the h5 file - this would be also very helpful! Tnx

i see the first few bytes of that file are: 'HDF5-based Julia Data Format, version 0.1.1� (Julia 1.3.1 64-bit' ... you may need to look for some Julia specific code to read ...

fyi, you may want to get back to the owner of the file, online readers baulked at exploring (https://h5web.panosc.eu/h5wasm for example) , i didn't progress any further in my attempts at walking through the structure though i did manage a few more dir() ...
